# Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with Windows 8.1 failure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have an HP Pavilion g6 (refer to image of the BIOS for the tech details) BIOS version f.26, vendor: insyde, which I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04.

I have done the following so far:

1. created a 150 GB partition where I intend to load Ubuntu
2. created a live USB of Ubuntu 14.04
3. disabled fast boot
4. enabled legacy boot in UEFI
5. disabled secure boot in UEFI

The trouble is, for a reason yet unknown to me, the machine still boots straight into Windows, and when I press F9 to select boot from UEFI, it takes me to some folders where I get lost. These are the images of the machine and the error I got when I attempted to boot into UEFI mode.

```
UUI,  [Acpi(PNP0A03, 0)/Pci(1110)/Ata(Primary , Master)/HDD(Part2,SigF3753910-CA64-4C6C-8DA2-9181C0556293)]
```

Comment: Upload your image here http://tinypic.com/ and post direct link in question. someone will edit that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an suggestion but have a problem

Problem : i can boot ubuntu but cannot boot windows 8, think twice before you act, if you wish to boot ubuntu very much try the following steps

Step:
Press windows key + I, a small window should appear on the right
Press change pc settings
Press update and recovery, choose recovery, and then press restart button of advanced setup
Press troubleshoot (refresh/reset your pc, or use advanced tools), and press advanced options, choose UEFI firmware settings, press restart button

Choose BIOS setup and then boot option
Press arrows to select security
Then you can see OS manager, USB drive/hard drive, etc, change the order, the one holding Ubuntu should be on the top
Save and exit